# Sums of Binomials

Tags: probability

I want to understand how to sum binomials and I can not figure out how this comes together:

$$\sum _{l=0}^k \binom{x}{l} \binom{y}{k-l}=\binom{x+y}{k}$$

Comment: Im sorry for that dupe, after reading your answer I am going to close this by myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be a duplicate, but the combinatorial argument is:

- Choose a team of $k$ from $x$ girls and $y$ boys by having $l$ girls and $k-l$ boys and summing over possible $l$
- Choose a team of $k$ from from $x$ girls and $y$ boys by treating them as $x+y$ children

Comment: "Please strive not to post more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs" - Bill Dubuque, aka the King of Duplicates